# create complex multiple dynamic objects to create a nested json

Tags: c#

New to creating json, but need to prepare some data to send to API so time to learn.

This is what I want to create;

```
[
  {
    "alias": "H02010",
    "address": "Demoroad 9",
    "city": "Demotown",
    "customer_id": "727",
    "property_id": "02010",
    "services": [
      {
        "description": "Service1",
        "shortname": "S1",
        "orderdates": [
          "2020-11-30",
          "2020-12-14",
          "2020-12-28"
        ]
      },
      {
        "description": "Service2",
        "shortname": "S2",
        "orderdates": [
          "2020-11-19",
          "2020-12-17"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

The challange is that there can be everything between 1 to 10 services that needs to be generated.
To create a "static" version of above I've made this;

```
        public class Anlobject 
        {
            public string alias { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string customer_id { get; set; }
            public string property_id { get; set; }
            public Services services { get; set; }
            public Services2 services2 { get; set; }

        }
        public class Services
        {
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string shortname { get; set; }
            public string[] dates { get; set; }
        }
        public class Services2
        {
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string shortname { get; set; }
            public string[] dates { get; set; }
        }

    private static Anlobject CreateAnlobject()
        {
            var obj = new Anlobject()
            {
                alias = "H02010",
                address = "Demoroad 9",
                city = "Demotown",
                customer_id = "727",
                property_id = "02010",
                services = new Services()
                {
                    description = "Service1",
                    shortname = "S1",
                    orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01","2020-02-01"},
                },
                services2 = new Services2()
                {
                    description = "Service2",
                    shortname = "S2",
                    orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01" },
                },
            };
            return obj;
        }

        private void bTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = CreateAnlobject();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\jSonTestTK.json", json.ToString());
        }
```

Is there a way to just have one Services() but call it several times, or am I totally on wrong track?

Thanks in advance for any hints where to look or search.

Comment: just keep an array of Service and use a for loop? am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example code.

The model looks like below. You dont need Services2

```
public class Service //create class as singular
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public string[] orderdates { get; set; }
}

public class Anlobject
{
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public string property_id { get; set; }
    public List<Service> services { get; set; }
}
```

`CreateAnlobject` function

```
private static Anlobject CreateAnlobject()
{
    var service1 = new Service()
    {
        description = "Service1",
        shortname = "S1",
        orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01" },
    };
    var service2 = new Service()
    {
        description = "Service2",
        shortname = "S2",
        orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01" },
    };

    var obj = new Anlobject()
    {
        alias = "H02010",
        address = "Demoroad 9",
        city = "Demotown",
        customer_id = "727",
        property_id = "02010",
        services = new List<Service> { service1, service2}
    };
    return obj;
}
```

Call the method from Main method

```
var obj = CreateAnlobject();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<Anlobject> { obj }); //you need list of Anlobject
File.WriteAllText("c:\\rnd\\jSonTestTK.json", json.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (or want) a `Services2` class or `services2` property.  The `services` property is a *collection* of `Services` objects.  (Though I'd recommend the name `Service` for the class instead.)

The property would be something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Services> services { get; set; }
```

And initializing it something like this:

```
services = new List<Services>
{
    new Services()
    {
        description = "Service1",
        shortname = "S1",
        orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01","2020-02-01"},
    },
    new Services()
    {
        description = "Service2",
        shortname = "S2",
        orderdates = new string[] { "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01" },
    }
}
```